# The this keyword in onclick handler is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Apologizes if it is very dumb. I cannot make `this` work in a `click` event:

```
<div onclick='hello()'>
     Click here!
</div>

<script>
    function hello() {
        // I want to do some works with *this* object
        alert(this.textContent);
    }
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `onclick='hello()'` missing `()`

Comment: @Satpal No. I want to deal with *this*

Comment: "I want to have access to this object in hello function." — What value do you want `this` to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value

```
<div onclick='hello.call(this)'></div>
```

```html
<div onclick='hello.call(this)'>
  Click here!
</div>
<script>
  function hello() {
    console.log(this.textContent);

  }
</script>
```

Or

[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) can also be used.

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value,

```html
<div onclick='hello.bind(this)()'>
  Click here!
</div>
<script>
  function hello() {
    console.log(this.textContent);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Using `.call()` is interesting...is there some advantage in doing so?

Comment: @zer00ne, what advantage? It only sets the `this` context

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the workaround. But can I ask help me understand why directly addressing name of function doesn't work?

Comment: @Hans, I don't have precise answer of above. As per my understanding its designed as such and remember these are [`Event-handler Attributes`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Attributes/_Global#Event-handler_Attributes)

Comment: @Satpal Posted a _why/how_ in my answer

Comment: @LGSon, I am aware of _why/how_ but I didn't had the precise answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addEventListener` instead of the inline handler, which I actually would recommend.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
})
```

```html
<div>
  Click here!
</div>
```

---

In addition to `call()`/`bind()`, you can pass the `this` like this as well, and simply use the passed parameter.

```html
    <div onclick='hello(this)'>
        Click here!
    </div>
    <script>
        function hello(el) {
            console.log(el.textContent);
        }
    </script>
```

---

> ### The value of `this` within the handler
>
> When attaching a handler function to an element using
>   [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), the value of `this` inside the handler is a
>   reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the
>   `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the
>   handler.
>
> If an event attribute (e.g., `onclick`) is specified on an element in
>   the HTML source, the JavaScript code in the attribute value is
>   effectively wrapped in a handler function that binds the value of this
>   in a manner consistent with the use of [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) an
>   occurrence of `this` within the code represents a reference to the
>   element. **Note** that the value of `this` inside a function *called by* the
>   code in the attribute value behaves as per [standard rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Src: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: @Hans Updated my answer with a _why_